# C# Cycling through image list and displaying one image in the picturebox

Tags: c#, image, listview, picturebox, imagelist

I have a problem cycling through an image list by pressing the next button and displaying the selected image in picturebox. What I want to do in my code is for user to click btnNext and to check if image value in picture box is less than what’s in the image list.

If it is then select that next image in the listbox (containing imagelist) and display it in picturebox. I’m not sure how to do all that though. Here is the code. Just to be clear the error is in 2nd if statement of btnNext_Click. Error says **"Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Image'"**  [GUI at runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBBqB.jpg)

```
string _big_fileName;
int _counter = 0;

public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Displays larger instance of selected image in picture box.
    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //FOR i is less than the first image.
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SelectedItems.Count;i++)
        {                
            //GET filename from listview and store in index.
            _big_fileName = listView1.SelectedItems[i].Text;
            //Create larger instance of image.
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(_big_fileName);
            //Fill panel to the width and height of picture box.
            panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(pictureBox1.Image.Width, 
                                                pictureBox1.Image.Height);
        }
    }

private void mnuOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadImageList();
    }

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            //IF Image is less than Image list size.
            if (pictureBox1.Image < imageList1.Images.Count)
            {
                //ACCESS Imagelist size against image value
                _big_fileName = listView1.SelectedItems[_counter].Text;
                //INCREMENT Image list current position.
                _counter++;
                //ASSIGN current position to image.
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(_big_fileName);
                //DISPLAY and enlarge image.
                panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(pictureBox1.Image.Width,
                                                pictureBox1.Image.Height);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No image.");
        }
    }

private void loadImageList()
    {
        imageList1.Images.Clear();
        listView1.Clear();

        oFD1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        oFD1.Title = "Open an Image File";
        oFD1.Filter = "JPEGS|*.jpg|GIFS|*.gif|PNGS|*.png|BMPS|*.bmp";

        //Open Dialog Box.
        var oldResults = oFD1.ShowDialog();

        if (oldResults == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            //GET amount of filenames.
            int num_of_files = oFD1.FileNames.Length;
            //Store filenames in string array.
            string[] arryFilePaths = new string[num_of_files];


            //FOREACH filename in the file.
            foreach (string single_file in oFD1.FileNames)
            {
                //ACCESS array using _counter to find file.
                arryFilePaths[_counter] = single_file;
                //CREATE image in memory and add image to image list.
                imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(single_file));

                _counter++;
            }
            //BIND image list to listview.
            listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;


            for (int i = 0; i < _counter; i++)
            {
                //DISPLAY filename and image from image index param. 
                listView1.Items.Add(arryFilePaths[i], i);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: _if (pictureBox1.Image < imageList1.Images.Count)_ - Well, the message is clear, isn't it?? Note that you can't deduce from a Picturebox what image it show; so you need to keep track of which one is loaded at each time! Use you class level variable `counter_`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Answer mostly changed based on your comment. You will need to create a new member variable to hold the current image index and make sure that is used to access the ImageList

Create a member variable to hold the current image index:

```
int _imageIndex;
```

Add this line to your `mnuOpen_Click` function after the call to `loadImageList();`

```
_imageIndex = 0;
```

In the function `btnNext_Click` make the changes:

```
if (pictureBox1.Image < imageList1.Images.Count)
```

to

```
if (_imageIndex < imageList1.Images.Count)
```

and

```
_big_fileName = listView1.SelectedItems[_counter].Text;
```

to

```
_big_fileName = listView1.SelectedItems[_imageIndex].Text;
```

and add the line

```
_imageIndex++;
```

Reworking of the `btnNext_Click` event handler

```
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //IF Image is less than Image list size.
        if (_imageIndex < imageList1.Images.Count)
        {
            listView1.Items[_imageIndex].Selected = true;

            _imageIndex++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't exactly make it perform the way I want it to because the counter has the same value as the total image list length so it will never get triggered. I added an image to show what the GUI is doing at runtime. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBBqB.jpg See the desert thumbnail? When I click btnNext, I want to select the next image in the list view on the left and display it in the picture box on the right. How can I do that, please?

Comment: JayV and @TaW it executes the IF statement and doesn’t do anything upon first iteration. When I click btnNext again it returns an error on the 2nd iteration of if statement. 
`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index`

Comment: @JordanNash I put another change in for the `btnNext_Click` event handler. How I tested...Load the images, click next several times

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just for overview sakes I’m trying to understand what you did on this line.
`listView1.Items[_imageIndex].Selected = true;`
So you’re accessing the items in the list view and using a new counter for the images and selecting it with the `Selected` property to fire up the event `listView1_SelectedIndexChanged`. From there you’re looping through all the items to get to the one after the currently selected one. Ok. Hope I’m reading that right or coming close at least.
One last thing please, would it have been easier had I given a dropbox link to the actual application?

Comment: @JordanNash Read it exactly correctly. As for DropBox link - No. My work proxy blocks access to fileshare services **AND** it makes for really bad questions/answers as external links can disappear over time